# Nautilus needs very long to open

Tags: nautilus

I'm working with Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit, Desktop) since 3 weeks now and today I got a problem with Nautilus. When I tried to open it, it took very long (more than 1 minute) to open.

Only a pc restart could solve that problem.

Now I'm worried that this problem might come up again.

Is there something I can do instead of restarting my pc, when that error occurs again?

Edit:

I tried to call it via terminal and got this error:

> Nautilus-Share-Message: 15:58:09.815: Called "net usershare info" but
> it failed: Kindprozess »net« konnte nicht ausgeführt werden (No such
> file or directory)

(sorry for parts of it being in german, I'm german :) - but maybe that already helps you!)

Comment: Did you have any stalled mounts? Maybe you mounted an online resource, that is not available anymore...

Comment: @pLumo Not that I know, no.